# set clipboard content in any browser

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser, clipboard, html

I need to set my user's clipboard when they trigger an event on my webpage. I realize each browser has a different way to do this, so do you know of a library or code snippet that will achieve this cross-browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article might help you with that : 
[Copy to Clipboard with Javascript on Mozilla firefox and IE](http://www.logiclabz.com/javascript/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-and-ie.aspx)

The basic idea is to :

- use `window.clipboardData` for Internet Explorer
- and use some flash component for Mozilla

Seems that this doesn't work with Flash 10, though, from some reports I've seen *(never tried myself)*

And/Or here is another solution *(still using Flash -- but seems to be working with Flash 10, for this one)* : [Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)