# HeadLessException when using getSystemClipboard().setContents(..)

Tags: java, websphere, clipboard

I have a Java application that has a line of code that says:

```
String myString="Some Text";
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(myString, null);
```

And this works great when I run my application in Eclipse with Java 5. When I create a .ear file and deploy it on websphere i get an exception that looks like this:

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
      at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getSystemClipboard(HeadlessToolkit.java:306)
      at something.something.something.package$MyButtonListener.buttonClick(View.java:271)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
      at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:512)
```

I can't seem to solve this, does anyone have any ideas? I understand that it is trying to set the clipboard on the server but how do I set it on the user of the webapplications computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your WebSphere environment does not have a monitor-based GUI ("head").

What is your intention in setting the clipboard on a server?

EDIT: All the `Toolkit` methods apply to the computer running the Java code.  If you want to manipulate the client, you need to deploy client-side code.  See [Set clipboard content in any browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025954/set-clipboard-content-in-any-browser).

Comment: I would like to set the clipboard on the computer that is accessing the webapplication, not the server. But maybe that is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the AWT method when you are running a gui-application on the client.

For a server-side application you don't have that gui, because you are just rendering pages. The server is actually running headless(no screen attached) so you get a HeadLessException.

You need to render some javascript or flash in your pages that cause the copying to clipboard: [How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)